# How to get the node from a click event in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am receiving the event from my onPress handler but I am not getting the node information.  I need to get the node so that I can compare it to another node to see if it's the same thing that was clicked or not.  How can this be done in react native?

```
    getNodeInfo(e) {
        console.log('e: ', e)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback ref={node => this.node = node} onPress={(e) => this.getNodeInfo(e)} style={{zIndex: 0}}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                        <ProductsContainer data={{productsList: { results: products }}}/>
                    </ScrollView>
                    <SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the access of the following *props* as mentioned here in the [`nativeEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html)

To get the `target: The node id of the element receiving the touch event`, you can simple log

```
getNodeInfo(e) {
        console.log('e: ', e.nativeEvent.target)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {..}
  this.getNodeInfo = this.getNodeInfo.bind(this);
} 
getNodeInfo(){
  console.log(this.node)
}
```

Comment: There is no need to bind it again since it has been already referenced here `onPress={(e) => this.getNodeInfo(e)}`